# Laravel administrator before_save() is not firing

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am getting userid from sentry and when creating or updating records, I need to update user_id to the posts too. I am using before_save() callback on the config.`Sentry::getUser()->id` is working correctly(i checked the function on routes and it is correctly providing user_id). While creating a post through administrator,  user_id is not being updated and hence the error.

```
/**
 * app/config/administrator/posts.php
 */

return array(

    'title' => 'Posts',

    'single' => 'post',

    'model' => 'Post',

    /**
     * The display columns
     */
    'columns' => array(
        'user' => array(
            'title' => 'User',
            'relationship' => 'user',
            'select' => "(:table).email",
        ),      
        'category' => array(
            'title' => 'Category',
            'relationship' => 'category',
            'select' => "(:table).name",
        ),  
        'pricing' => array(
            'title' => 'Pricing',
            'relationship' => 'pricing',
            'select' => "(:table).name",
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'title' => 'Name',
            'select' => "name",
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'title' => 'Title',
            'select' => "title",
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'title' => 'Description',
            'select' => "description",
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'title' => 'Order',
            'select' => "order_value",
        ),
        'active_date' => array(
            'title' => 'Start',
            'select' => "active_date",
        ),
        'expiry_date' => array(
            'title' => 'End',
            'select' => "expiry_date",
        ),
        'status' => array(
            'title' => 'Status',
            'select' => "status",
        )
    ),

    /**
     * The filter set
     */
    // 'filters' => array(
    //  'name' => array(
    //      'title' => 'Name',
    //  ),
    //  'description' => array(
    //      'title' => 'Description',
    //      'type' => "text",
    //  )
    // ),


    'before_save' => function(&$data)
    {
        $data['user_id'] = Sentry::getUser()->id;
        // return $data;
    },

    /**
     * The editable fields
     */
    'edit_fields' => array( 
        'category' => array(
            'title' => 'Category',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'name_field' => "name",
        ),  
        'pricing' => array(
            'title' => 'Pricing',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'name_field' => "name",
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'title' => 'Name',
            'type' => "text",
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'title' => 'Title',
            'type' => "text",
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'title' => 'Description',
            'type' => "textarea",
        ),
        'active_date' => array(
            'title' => 'Start',
            'type' => "date",
        ),
        'expiry_date' => array(
            'title' => 'End',
            'type' => "date",
        ),
        'status' => array(
            'title' => 'Status',
            'type' => "bool",
        )
    ),


);
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is administrator's bug or my ignorance, I solved this with another method. Into posts model, I created events for creating and updating posts:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($post)
    {
        $post->user_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    });

    static::updating(function($post)
    {
        $post->user_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    });
}
```